# Failed DEM via Natural Neighbor, QGIS 3.16-6 Hannover

Tags: qgis-3, dem, ubuntu

Reading [How to Create DEM and Elevation Profile in QGIS](https://www.geodose.com/2018/09/how-to-create-dem-elevation-profile-qgis.html), I can't generate DEM from vertices layer using Natural neighbour with height whatever the cell size and parameters.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, QGIS installed with flatpak. HDD 100GB avail.
[image: settings]

Getting:

```
QGIS version: 3.16.6-Hannover
QGIS code revision: bfd36fdd
Qt version: 5.15.3
GDAL version: 3.2.1
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
SAGA version 7.6.3 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Natural neighbour' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'FIELD' : 'height', 'METHOD' : 0, 'SHAPES' : '/media/pm/Data/Downloads/vertices.geojson|layername=vertices', 'TARGET_OUT_GRID' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'TARGET_TEMPLATE' : None, 'TARGET_USER_FITS' : 0, 'TARGET_USER_SIZE' : 0.15, 'TARGET_USER_XMIN TARGET_USER_XMAX TARGET_USER_YMIN TARGET_USER_YMAX' : '-146.000000000,152.416666667,-80.916666667,64.000000000 [EPSG:4326]', 'WEIGHT' : 0 }

grid_gridding "Natural Neighbour" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -SHAPES "/tmp/processing_WmXshU/b1c91a0db1464037b1d72d688bd36dcf/SHAPES.shp" -FIELD "height" -METHOD 0 -TARGET_USER_XMIN -146.0 -TARGET_USER_XMAX 152.416666667 -TARGET_USER_YMIN -80.916666667 -TARGET_USER_YMAX 64.0 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 0.15 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -WEIGHT 0.0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "/tmp/processing_WmXshU/d3966278eae04c1c90f2d7e7b7ccb382/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 7.6.3

Unknown option 'SHAPES'
____________________________
library path: /app/lib/saga/
library name: libgrid_gridding
library : grid_gridding
tool : Natural Neighbour
identifier : 3
author : O.Conrad (c) 2008
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________


Usage: saga_cmd grid_gridding 3 [-POINTS <str>] [-FIELD <str>] [-TARGET_DEFINITION <str>] [-TARGET_USER_SIZE <double>] [-TARGET_USER_XMIN <double>] [-TARGET_USER_XMAX <double>] [-TARGET_USER_YMIN <double>] [-TARGET_USER_YMAX <double>] [-TARGET_USER_COLS <num>] [-TARGET_USER_ROWS <num>] [-TARGET_USER_FITS <str>] [-TARGET_TEMPLATE <str>] [-TARGET_OUT_GRID <str>] [-METHOD <str>] [-WEIGHT <double>]
-POINTS:<str> Points
Shapes (input)
-FIELD:<str> Attribute
Table field
-TARGET_DEFINITION:<str> Target Grid System
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] user defined
[1] grid or grid system
Default: 0
-TARGET_USER_SIZE:<double> Cellsize
Floating point
Minimum: 0.000000
Default: 1.000000
-TARGET_USER_XMIN:<double> West
Floating point
Default: 0.000000
-TARGET_USER_XMAX:<double> East
Floating point
Default: 100.000000
-TARGET_USER_YMIN:<double> South
Floating point
Default: 0.000000
-TARGET_USER_YMAX:<double> North
Floating point
Default: 100.000000
-TARGET_USER_COLS:<num> Columns
Integer
Minimum: 1
Default: 100
-TARGET_USER_ROWS:<num> Rows
Integer
Minimum: 1
Default: 100
-TARGET_USER_FITS:<str> Fit
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] nodes
[1] cells
Default: 0
-TARGET_TEMPLATE:<str> Target System
Grid (optional input)
-TARGET_OUT_GRID:<str> Target Grid
Grid (output)
-METHOD:<str> Method
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] Linear
[1] Sibson
[2] Non-Sibsonian
Default: 1
-WEIGHT:<double> Minimum Weight
Floating point
Maximum: 0.000000
Default: 0.000000
corrupted double-linked list
/home/pm/.var/app/org.qgis.qgis/data/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/saga_batch_job.sh: line 1: 76 Aborted (core dumped) saga_cmd grid_gridding "Natural Neighbour" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -SHAPES "/tmp/processing_WmXshU/b1c91a0db1464037b1d72d688bd36dcf/SHAPES.shp" -FIELD "height" -METHOD 0 -TARGET_USER_XMIN -146.0 -TARGET_USER_XMAX 152.416666667 -TARGET_USER_YMIN -80.916666667 -TARGET_USER_YMAX 64.0 -TARGET_USER_SIZE 0.15 -TARGET_USER_FITS 0 -WEIGHT 0.0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "/tmp/processing_WmXshU/d3966278eae04c1c90f2d7e7b7ccb382/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat"
Execution completed in 1.57 seconds
Results:
{'TARGET_OUT_GRID': '/tmp/processing_WmXshU/d3966278eae04c1c90f2d7e7b7ccb382/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /tmp/processing_WmXshU/4397f9a7887a4a2f80070fce4193b0cd/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat
• /tmp/processing_WmXshU/d3966278eae04c1c90f2d7e7b7ccb382/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Also tried with other cellsizes (100, 0.0005, 0.0002, ...).

Adding the [vertices.geojson](https://github.com/j2l/minijs/blob/main/verticesgeojson.zip) (zipped) layer for you to test.